# NFSv4 - EOFException

Tags: java, nfs

I have the following problem:

This code...

```
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(serializedKeyIndex);
        in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);  // this line throws the EOFException (and IOException)
        keys = (HashMap<String, String>) in.readObject();
        in.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // create the key index
        keys = new HashMap<String, String>();
        storeKeyIndex(bucket, keys);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new DataAccessResourceFailureException(
                "Unable to store Bucket: " + bucket, e);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new DataAccessResourceFailureException(
                "Unable to store Bucket: " + bucket, e);
    }
```

...of the littles3 server implementation (http://code.google.com/p/littles3/source/browse/trunk/modules/filesystem/src/main/java/com/jpeterson/littles3/dao/filesystem/FileS3ObjectDao.java, in line 474) throws an EOFException on a mounted NFS version 4 drive.

The report of Glassfish shows me:

```
 [#|2012-09-19T10:46:00.277+0200|WARNING|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID
 java.io.EOFException
     at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2298)
     at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2767)
     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:798)
     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:298)
     at com.jpeterson.littles3.dao.filesystem.FileS3ObjectDao.retrieveKeyIndex(FileS3ObjectDao.java:474)
     at com.jpeterson.littles3.dao.filesystem.FileS3ObjectDao.loadS3Object(FileS3ObjectDao.java:63)
     at com.jpeterson.littles3.service.impl.FileStorageServiceImpl.load(FileStorageServiceImpl.java:89)
     at com.jpeterson.littles3.StorageEngine.methodPut(StorageEngine.java:823)
     at com.jpeterson.littles3.StorageEngine.doService(StorageEngine.java:233)
     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:475)
     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:450)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:691)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
     at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
     at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
     at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
     at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
     at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
```

The odd thing is that it works fine with usual local file system. No exception there.

The error only occurs with NFSv4 if I want to create a second S3Object (folder or file) below a bucket. It seems that it can only create one S3Object below a bucket there. As I said already, it works fine on a usual file system.

Might a file lock cause that problem? Has someone gained experiences here already?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Update: I got the permission to store some information in a local file system instead of the mounted NFS drive. Maybe I can solve the problem in that way.

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that the file is empty.

Comment: Many thanks, I have stored the HashMap keys (meta information) into another file system location (local file system like ext4) meanwhile. It works fine there. So I really think that it was the file lock of the NFSv4. It only allows to create and delete files there, but it doesn't allow to change files there. That's okay and it's wanted.

That means buckets are stored in NFS, the meta information is stored elsewhere.